# Ionic applicaiton set css translate3d not run in my device

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I create a menu side in my app ionic and set css for it. here is my code
menu.html

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false" >
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">

        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent" ></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
     <div class="bar-header">
     </div>
    </ion-header-bar>
    
 <ion-content class="custom">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close>
        Tab 1
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

and in style.css i added:

```css
.menu.menu-left{
 width: calc(75%) !important;
}
.menu-open .menu-content{
 transform: translate3d(calc(75%), 0px, 0px) !important;
}
```

and when I run application in my device I see css

```css
.menu-open .menu-content{
     transform: translate3d(calc(75%), 0px, 0px) !important;
    }
```

not run . I'm try add class platform-android in tag body and add .platfrom-android.menu-open... but it not run.
How I can fix it or how I can set width of menu side is 75% screen width?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to set width you don't need `calc`.

```
width: 75%;
```

Comment: It look like same, no slove problem